# WebDriver getting the label tag value using Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML code:

```
<label id="busquedaSimpleForm:j_idt36" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Results found: 2</label>
```

From the above label, I want to get the `Results found: 2` value.

Below is my Java source code:

```
WebElement tf = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='busquedaSimpleForm:j_idt36']"));
String fdl = tf.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(fdl);
```

But my source code output becomes empty.

Please help me what is the problem on my XPath.

Comment: should use getText(), rather than getAttribute('value'), try label[id*='busquedaSimpleForm'] in browser DevTool, if it matched more than one element,  and the 'j_idt36' is dynamical value,  you need to give more HTML code, so that we can narrow the search scope start its parent nodes

Comment: @Prabhu, Any issue with `getText` method ?

Comment: Just putting a single line of HTML DOM is not a good option . Since its look like a dynamic id value so you should add extra information and  give details of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no attribute `value` in that HTML line, you should use `.getText()` and since you're looking for an element with that ID (provided no other elements use that same ID) you can just do `findElement(By.id(...));`:

```
    WebElement tf = driver.findElement(By.id("busquedaSimpleForm:j_idt36"));
    String fdl = tf.getText();
    System.out.println(fdl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem is you have to get the innerHTML value. The code will be like below:

```
WebElement  elem = driver.findElement(By.id("busquedaSimpleForm:j_idt36"));
String str = elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(str);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

To retrive the text `Results found: 2` for the provided `HTML` you can use the following line of code :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='ui-outputlabel ui-widget' and contains(@id,'busquedaSimpleForm:')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: @Prabu Did you get a chance to evaluate my answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this xpath:- `//label[text()='Results found: 2']`

Seems your id is dynamic so don't use it

Comment: text and count was dynamic

Comment: You should mention that in your question so it help to find correct ans